# React Native: How to use externally declared variables inside JSX return

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to create an app that has an onboarding sequence that is only shown on the first launch. During onboarding, the user is asked to enter their name and I am able to use whether or not there is a name value stored to determine if the app is being launched for the first time or if there is an existing user on the device. The idea is to assign a variable to a string value that corresponds to the first element to render; <Onboarding /> or <Home />, bypassing onboarding on 2nd... 3rd... launch etc. However, when I assign the variable values outside of the return() statement, I get the error: `Property 'initial' doesn't exist` in Expo GO. I am a beginner to React Native and mobile app development so sorry if the fix is super obvious; any help would be appreciated! Below is an abridged version of the code in my runtime `App.js` file. (Note that the username has been stored Async with the key 'user'. Thanks again!

````
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import Onboarding from './screens/Onboarding'
import Onboarding2 from './screens/Onboarding2'
import Onboarding3 from './screens/Onboarding3'
import Onboarding4 from './screens/Onboarding4'
import Onboarding5 from './screens/Onboarding5'
import Home from './appscreens/Home'
import About from './appscreens/About'
import Name from './screens/Name'


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const navTheme = {
  colors: {
    background: 'transparent'
  }
}

export default function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  const findUser = async () => {
    const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    setUser(JSON.parse(result))
    console.log(user)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    findUser()
  }, [])

  if (!user.name){const initial = "Onboarding"}
  if (user.name){const initial = "Home"}

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={navTheme}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initial} screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding2" component={Onboarding2} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding3" component={Onboarding3} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding4" component={Onboarding4} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding5" component={Onboarding5} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Name" component={Name} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}); ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is apparent. You are accessing variable `initial` outside its defined scope:

Refactor code as below :

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Onboarding from "./screens/Onboarding";
import Onboarding2 from "./screens/Onboarding2";
import Onboarding3 from "./screens/Onboarding3";
import Onboarding4 from "./screens/Onboarding4";
import Onboarding5 from "./screens/Onboarding5";
import Home from "./appscreens/Home";
import About from "./appscreens/About";
import Name from "./screens/Name";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const navTheme = {
  colors: {
    background: "transparent",
  },
};

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState("OnBoarding");

  const findUser = async () => {
    const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    setUser(JSON.parse(result));
    console.log(user);

    if (user?.name) {
      setInitialRoute("Home");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    findUser();
  }, []);

  if (!user) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={navTheme}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={initialRoute}
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding2" component={Onboarding2} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding3" component={Onboarding3} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding4" component={Onboarding4} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding5" component={Onboarding5} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Name" component={Name} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding couple of things to your code . First set a state variable and declare the initial value as follows,

```js
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState("Onboarding"); // Declare the initial state here
```

And then , Update the initial state based on the user's presence

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      if (user.name) {
        setInitial("Home");
      } else {
        setInitial("Onboarding");
      }
    }, [user]);
```

Now, the app should correctly determine whether to show the onboarding or home screen based on whether the user's name exists in the storage.